# Unable to get the restored site collection in new farm after Content DB Backup- on premises

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, restore, contentdb-backup

am trying to get the web application created in one farm and port it into  another farm having the same db sp 2013 versions.

I am having 3 sites

1) publishing portal site collection

2) search center site collec.

3) one archived site collection of (1) -a replica of  first site collec

I took the  sql content db backup from my sql srvr machine and "mywebapp_contentdb.bak" and  took it onto my target farm machine.

I restored the  content db using SSMS tool and its restored successfully.

I created a new web appln in my target farm and and gave the name of the content db - that's restored in my sql srvr machine- in the text box provided for my web appln.

I created the web appln successfully and it has 3 sites as in the source sp farm.

the issue is , when I navigate to the site collection page, it shows me error

> page can not be displayed
>
> [image: restored-content-db]

Comment: Try to reenable the publishing features using powershell. Looks like the pages library might be lost? Does the other site collections work?

Comment: ok,,, lemme try and  revert here...

Comment: I tried with the stsadm command and ran the activatefeature , stsadm -o activatefeature -name PublishingResources -url "http://vgsrvr-01:28516/"
stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishing\feature.xml -url "http://vgsrvr-01:28516/" -force  but it didn't work , again am getting the same issue : page cant be displayed :

Comment: Do the other site collections work? Are you able to navigate to site contents by adding /_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx to your site url instead of /pages/home.aspx or sitepages/home.aspx?

Comment: no, those sites are also not working, I have checked for my ent.search center and the  3rd site - that's an "archived site collec-" . Am trying to remove the complete web appln, and redo the process again. Am having a doubt here, after restoring the content db, am trying to create a  new web appln. instead of providing the restored content db name and let the sharepoint create a new content db as it provides by default and once the  web app is created , I can mount the restored content db to this new web appln. Will this approach work?

Comment: Just reread your description and i dont think creating a new webapplication and naming the database the same will work. Try to run the powershell cmdlt mount-spcontentdatabase with correct parameter to see if it makes any difference

Comment: I have tried the 2nd approach mentioned in this blog: https://waziray.wordpress.com/2015/03/30/how-to-mount-existing-contentdb-to-a-sharepoint-web-application/

Comment: But did you try to mount the database using powershell instead?

Comment: no,i removed the existing content db created for web appln, thru central admin UI and added the backed-up db through central admin only